# javascript variable value in asynchronous function called simultaneously by multiple clients

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, scope, server

I am putting up a web server in node.js, 
in particular I am developing a module for orders management.

the module is wrapped inside an anonymous function

```
(function(){})();
```

if the "insertOrder" function I declare the variable order like this:

```
    var order = {
      user_id: '',
      address_id: '',
      payed: false,
      accepted: false,
      shipped: false
    };
```

Then it gets populated with the values "returned" from the asynchronous functions i am calling that interact with the database.

This application is going to be used simultaneously by multiple clients.

Now, assuming that two users want to make an order, is the variable going to be re-initialized to the starting object every time the function get's called, overwriting the changes made during the first execution? Or is a context going to be spawned every time a client makes a call to the server? 
I know this is not the case for node.js but still can't figure this one 
out.

I.E.
is the variable value of the previous iteration gonna be kept somehow and used until the end of the first function call or lost as soon as the function gets called again?

Thank you very much.

EDIT: further explaination of the problem.

The user_id is is going to be used to retrieve the address that the order is going to be shipped to. A wrong user_id is going to result in the item shipped to the wrong address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `var order = { ... }` is inside the `insertOrder` function, then every time the `insertOrder` function is called `order` will be reinitialized. The scope is isolated, so there should not be any mingling of local variables even in an asynchronous situation.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8u52nwgr/)

Comment: yeah but my question is: is the variable value of the previous iteration gonna be kept somehow and used until the end of the first function or lost as soon as the function gets called again?

Comment: problem with your js.fiddle: the function is resolving as soon as it gets called since it's not waiting for any asyncronous response, plus insertOrder() doesn't get called simoultaneously but instead is called after the first call ends, so it's a subsequent call

Comment: The function scopes are encapsulated so there shouldn't be any mingling of the variables. I added timeouts to the fiddle, but I'm not sure if that correctly demonstrates it. Are you unable to run tests in your environment?

Comment: yes, unfortunately I am unable to run tests at the moment, I'm trying to figure out the correct way to develop this module

Comment: the differences between the provided fiddle and my case are: the function that is going to respond asyncronously is insertOrder() and the calls from the client are happening while the function is still resolving.

Comment: Ok, I took one more shot at an example. The variables inside the function are isolated, so a second call to the same function creates a new scope.